# Reporting transfer datarate to an UI

Tags: c++

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application where I'm copying data from a remote file `ifstream` to a local file `ofstream`. The transfer code looks basically like this:

```
void MyTransferThread()
{
    std::ofstream local_file( /*...*/ );
    std::ifstream remote_file( /*...*/ );

    // an arbitrary block size
    const size_t buffer_size = 4096; 
    char buffer[ buffer_size ];

    while( remote_file )
    {
        remote_file.read( buffer, buffer_size );
        int read = remote_file.gcount();
        local_file.write( buffer, read );
    }
}
```

What's the best way to report the current rate of the transfer (in bytes/second) to a separate UI thread while having a minimal effect on the transfer speed?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the same as in my current application where I'm counting polygons drawn per second:

1. every iteration make `++count`
2. every `ITER` iterations

   1. `QueryPerformanceCounter()` or something similar and store in `new_time`
   2. `elapsed = new_time - old_time`, `old_time = new_time`, `if elapsed > THRESHOLD` then `throughput = count / elapsed * THRESHOLD` expressed in `counts per THRESHOLD`, reset `count`, display `throughput`.

My `THRESHOLD` is based on `QueryPerformanceFrequency()`, while one `count` for me is a specific scene I relate to, realizable in `ITER` steps. Unless we're talking about multi-gigabit, even the impact of `QueryPerformanceCounter()` should be negligible.

Comment: I'm not really talking about how to  calculate the throughput. I'm looking for reporting methods once it is calculated. For example, is it better to store the current throughput in a volatile member variable and have the other threads query that or to use a PostMessage to report it to the UI or have the UI register a callback function invoked by the thread?